# lagranges method

Tags: matlab

I found following code on internet. I am new to matlab. Now the problem whenever i copy-paste this code then it shows me error message.

```
function[p] = lagrange_interpolation(X,Y)
|
Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context.
```

The code snippet is:

```
function[p] = lagrange_interpolation(X,Y)

L = zeros(n);

p = zeros(1,n);


% computing L matrice, so that each row i holds the polynom L_i

% Now we compute li(x) for i=0....n  ,and we build the polynomial 

for k=1:n

    multiplier = 1;

    outputConv = ones(1,1);

    for index = 1:n

        if(index ~= k && X(index) ~= X(k))

            outputConv = conv(outputConv,[1,-X(index)]);

            multiplier = multiplier * ((X(k) - X(index))^-1);

        end

    end

    polynimialSize = length(outputConv);

    for index = 1:polynimialSize

        L(k,n - index + 1) = outputConv(polynimialSize - index + 1);

    end

    L(k,:) = multiplier .* L(k,:);

end

      % continues 

        end
```

Comment: Where are you pasting this? You should be putting it in the code editor

Comment: Also if you are indeed in the script window, make sure the first line is the `function [p] = ...` line and that you don't have any code in front of it

Comment: Did you ask your instructor/TA?

Comment: This is starting to sound like a 'What does this do?' question, and sounds like homework (too bad they removed the homework tag). This leads my question: are you attempting to use SO to cheat on a coding exercise for school?

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood, you are probably attempting to mix random code along with your function. There are two types of M files:

- scripts - have "random" code that is executed independent of anything else
- functions - are the "classic" definition of functions

You cannot mix the two (that's a lie, but for now a good one). So if you are defining a function, that should be the only code in your .m file.

You should later use this function in either the command window or another function or a script by calling it via `p = blahblah(bleaurgh);`.

TL;DR: Make sure the function code is the only code in the script file, save it with the same name.m, call the function from somewhere else.